# How vb.net core dll reference works in .net core

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-core, class-library

I have a C#.Net Core class library project A and VB.Net core class library project B. I am not able to reference the dll of VB.net core 2.2 project B from my .net core (c#) project A. I have added the assembly reference of B through Add Reference->Browse window. But the services/Methods from the vb project B is not accessible from project A.

Comment: Your title says "project reference" but your post says "assembly reference".  Which is it?  Are the projects in the same solution?  What EXACTLY have you tried to do that you expected to work but didn't and what exactly happened?  Have you used the Object Browser window to see that the expected assembly, namespace(s) and type(s) are accessible?

Comment: @ jmcilhinney I meant vb.net core project's dll. I have  edited the post.I can see the assemblies listed under the dependencies folder.

Comment: And what about the Object Browser?  I asked that for a reason.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Only the assembly name is showing in the object browser. Expected Namespaces or services are not listed.

Comment: Are you sure that your VB types are public?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yeah they are public .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200060/discussion-between-soumika-and-jmcilhinney).

Answer (score 2):

since .net-core2 you can add any net-core external DLLs to your project (vb-c#-f#).
just make sure the `target framework` is set to `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` on you vb project then just add the following section to your `.csproj` file :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="MyVBAssembly">
      <HintPath>path\to\MyVBAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

and you can use your VB Dll in your code like this:

```cs
  // where `MyVBAssembly` is your main namespace in VB
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var hw = new MyVBAssembly.HelloWorldVB();                           
      Console.WriteLine(hw.GetHelloWorld()); // 
  }
```

I tested this example with following class using external dll refrence:

```vb
' HelloWorldVB.vb 

Public Class HelloWorldVB   
    Public Function GetHelloWorld()
        return "Hello World"
    End Function
End Class
```

also if you have access to your vb project source code you can add a reference to it using CLI with this command :

```
cd path/to/csharp-project-folder
dotnet add reference path/to/vb-project-folder
```